# Helper file cant load in codeigniter subdomain

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain, codeigniter-3

i already moved my project into subdomain on a live server, and i found this error

```
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/app_helper.php
```

seems like the helper file can't load in a controller.
and here is my base url config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://log.mysite.co.id';
```

what i missed? is there any different configuration between main domain and subdomain setting?

Comment: check helper files is readable by apache, since you said moved to live server probably you forgot to set permission

Comment: before i moved to subdomain live server, i already uploaded it into main domain on live server and it works well